# Can Lombok exclude the value but still print the field name?

Tags: java, logging, lombok

I'm working on a Java application which handles multiple sensitive values. We are using Lombok, and have a lot of data classes which look like this the below. However, it's confusing to see these classes in the log with no indication that they contain some critical fields, as the generated toString will 100% ignore the excluded fields. Is it possible to have Lombok print something like `clientSecret=<HIDDEN>` without writing a custom toString for each class?

```
/** data we will send to token endpoint */
@Data
public class TokenReq {
    private String grantType;

    private String code;

    private String clientId;

    @ToString.Exclude
    private String refreshToken;

    @ToString.Exclude
    private String clientSecret;

    private String redirectUri;
}
```

Comment: a long time ago I stumbled across the same thing and there is no way to do it. what I did at the time is implement an interface with a default method that would take as input the names of the properties that need to be masked... and it would return the String representation of your object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude the field that should be masked and include a helper method that returns the masked value:

```
@Data
public class TokenReq {

    @ToString.Exclude
    private String clientSecret;

    @ToString.Include(name="clientSecret")
    private String hiddenClientSecretForToString() {
        return "<HIDDEN>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, the extra code needed scales only with the number of fields I need to "hide". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment this is how I did a while ago, it needs some more work probably, but here is the idea:

```
interface ToString {

    default String innerToString(String... exclusions) {
        Method[] allMethods = getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        return Arrays.stream(allMethods)
                     .filter(x -> x.getName().startsWith("get"))
                     .map(x -> {
                         if (Arrays.stream(exclusions).anyMatch(y -> ("get" + y).equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName()))) {
                             return x.getName().substring(3) + " = <HIDDEN>";
                         }

                         try {
                             return x.getName().substring(3) + " = " + x.invoke(this);
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             throw new RuntimeException(e);
                         }
                     })
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    }
}
```

And a class:

```
static class Person implements ToString {

    private String name;
    private String password;

    // constructor/getter or lombok annotations

    public String toString() {
        return innerToString("password");
    }
}
```

And then usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("eugene", "password");
    System.out.println(p);
}
```